# C# Wont save to database after 2nd Click

Tags: c#, database

So my program works as it should. When I click the save button everything is saved to the database. However when I click the save button a second time it fails to work.**Index was outside the bounds of the array.** is the error in private void btnTest_click on line string Ullage = splitstring[2];

```
  private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=E:\2014-06-26 TEK687 Config Tool\TEK687 Config Tool\bin\Debug\Results.mdb");

        string SqlString = "insert into Table1  (PassOrFail,DateTested,TekNum,BatchNum,WeekNum,Serial,FirmwareVer,HardwareVer,TestPC,SettingsTest,Deleted,Ullage,SRC,Vbatt,Tamb,Ullage2,SRC2,Vbatt2,Tamb2) Values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PassOrFail", txtPassFail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateTested", txtDateTested.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TekNum", txtTekPartNo.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("BatchNum", txtBatchNumber.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("WeekNum", txtWeekYearNo.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Serial", txtSerialNumber.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirmwareVer", txtFirmwareVer.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("HardwareVer", txtHardwareVer.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TestPC", txtTestPC.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SettingsTest", cboSettingsProfiles.SelectedIndex);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Deleted", txtDeleted.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Ullage", txtUllage1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SRC", txtSRC1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Vbatt", txtVbatt1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Tamb", txtTamb1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Ullage2", txtUllage2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SRC2", txtSRC2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Vbatt2", txtVbatt2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Tamb2", txtTamb2.Text);


            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data stored successfully");
        }

        ClearTextBoxes(this);
    }
```

Here is the code to add values to database error is at **string Ullage = splitstring[2];**

```
 private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cancel = false;
        if (DiscoverDevice(false) == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error, device is not responding");
            return;
        }

        string servo = "";
        MyModemSerialInterfaceLayer.WriteTextAndWaitForResponse("TL,S," + txtToolID.Text + ",30,\r\n", "\r\n", 4, ref servo, 500);

        string test = "";
        MyModemSerialInterfaceLayer.WriteTextAndWaitForResponse("TL,T," + txtToolID.Text + "\r\n", "\r\n", 4, ref test, 500);

        string[] splitstring = test.Split(',');
        **string Ullage = splitstring[2];**
        string SRC = splitstring[3];
        string RSSI = splitstring[4];
        string AlarmStatus = splitstring[5];
        string RateofChange = splitstring[6];
        string Tamb = splitstring[7];
        string Vbatt = splitstring[8];

        Ullage = Ullage.Replace("u:", "");
        Tamb = Tamb.Replace("t:", "");
        Vbatt = Vbatt.Replace("v:", "");
        int Ull = Convert.ToInt32(Ullage);
        int src = Convert.ToInt32(SRC);
        int BV = Convert.ToInt32(Vbatt);
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(Tamb);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(Ull);
        txtUllage1.Text += sb.ToString();
        StringBuilder sc = new StringBuilder();
        sc.Append(src);
        txtSRC1.Text += sc.ToString();
        StringBuilder sd = new StringBuilder();
        sd.Append(BV);
        txtVbatt1.Text += sd.ToString();
        StringBuilder se = new StringBuilder();
        se.Append(temp);
        txtTamb1.Text += se.ToString();
        StringBuilder sm = new StringBuilder();


        if ((Ull < 11) || (Ull > 13) || (src < 9) || (BV < 29))
        {
            txtPassFail.Text += "12cm FAIL";
              txtResultsReading.Font = new Font(txtResultsReading.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
            StringBuilder th = new StringBuilder();
               th.Append("12cm FAIL");
              txtResultsReading.Text += th.ToString();
        }

        string servoTwo = "";
        MyModemSerialInterfaceLayer.WriteTextAndWaitForResponse("TL,S," + txtToolID.Text + ",31,\r\n", "\r\n", 4, ref servoTwo, 500);
        string tests = "";
        MyModemSerialInterfaceLayer.WriteTextAndWaitForResponse("TL,T," + txtToolID.Text + "\r\n", "\r\n", 4, ref tests, 500);



        string[] splitstrings = tests.Split(',');
        string Ullage2 = splitstrings[2];
        string SRC2 = splitstrings[3];
        string RSSI2 = splitstrings[4];
        string AlarmStatus2 = splitstrings[5];
        string RateofChange2 = splitstrings[6];
        string Tamb2 = splitstrings[7];
        string Vbatt2 = splitstrings[8];

        Ullage2 = Ullage2.Replace("u:", "");
        Tamb2 = Tamb2.Replace("t:", "");
        Vbatt2 = Vbatt2.Replace("v:", "");
        int Ull2 = Convert.ToInt32(Ullage2);
        int src2 = Convert.ToInt32(SRC2);
        int BV2 = Convert.ToInt32(Vbatt2);
        int temp2 = Convert.ToInt32(Tamb2);

        StringBuilder sf = new StringBuilder();
        sf.Append(Ull2);
        txtUllage2.Text += sf.ToString();
        StringBuilder sg = new StringBuilder();
        sg.Append(src2);
        txtSRC2.Text += sg.ToString();
        StringBuilder sh = new StringBuilder();
        sh.Append(BV2);
        txtVbatt2.Text += sh.ToString();
        StringBuilder si = new StringBuilder();
        si.Append(temp2);
        txtTamb2.Text += si.ToString();


        txtDateTested.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        txtTestPC.Text = System.Environment.UserName;
        //boSettingsProfiles.Text= Settings.SettingsFile;
        txtDeleted.Text = "CURRENT";

        if ((Ull < 11) || (Ull > 13) || (src < 9) || (BV < 29))
        {

            txtPassFail.Text += "  3M FAIL";
            txtResultsReading.Font = new Font(txtResultsReading.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
            StringBuilder tg = new StringBuilder();
            tg.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            tg.Append("3M FAIL");
            txtResultsReading.Text += tg.ToString();
        }
        else if ((Ull >= 11) && (Ull <= 13) && (src == 9) && (BV >= 29) &&
            (Ull2 >= 11) && (Ull2 <= 13) && (src2 == 9) && (BV2 >= 29))
        {
            txtPassFail.Text += "PASS";
            txtResultsReading.Font = new Font(txtResultsReading.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
            txtResultsReading.Text += "PASS";
        }
        ReleaseDevice();//release the config tool after config is completed
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Or does it even reach your code the 2nd time?

Comment: Index was outside the bounds of the array is the error. But it works ok the first time I click the button

Comment: On what line does the error occur?

Comment: Please provie the full error message and point the line in error out so that one may help you further.

Comment: The connection creation shall be in a `using` block as well.

Comment: Look at the content of `test` on your second run.

Answer (score 3):

Your `splitstrings` object doesn't have three objects in it, therefore you can't access the object at index 2. Therefore, you should implement a check to make sure it contains an object at that index before accessing, then handle the case where it doesn't as appropriate.

By the way, next time you ask a question about why something doesn't work, it's absolutely critical that you tell us about the exception you're getting, rather than making us ask for it. And you need to include the code that throws the exception. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Inspect the variable coming out of the WriteTextAndWaitForResponse call. It probably doesn't have 3 commas.

Comment: string Ullage = splitstring[2]; throws the error clear check boxex is a function that clears all text boxes after save button is clicked